# How to update two different root children in update in Firebase for web

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data structure as below:

```
object: {
    "Team1": {
        "batsman": {
            "Batsman1": {
                "onStrike": "N"
            },
            "Batsman2": {
                "onStrike": "Y"
            }
        }
    }
};

object: {
    "Team1": {
        "batsman": {
            "Batsman1": {
                "onStrike": "N"
            },
            "Batsman2": {
                "onStrike": "Y"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and I want to change both batsmen `"onStrike"` value vice-versa on a button click.
    on button click, it should change As below

Answer (score 0):

Batsman 1 or Batsman 2 on strike are mutually exclusive. If batsman 1 is on strike then batsman 2 can't be and vice versa, so you only need to keep batsman 1 onStrike and set it to true or false.

If you insist on having redundant data on your database, then please indicate what language you are using to code and / or a code snippet of what you have tried.

**Update:**

I use Dart but in javascript should be something like:

```
 var atomicUpdate = {"/gblBattingTeam + "/batsman/Batsman1" + ":" + "onStrike": "N",
                     "/gblBattingTeam + "/batsman/Batsman2" + ":" + "onStrike": "Y",
                    }
 dbRefObject.update(atomicUpdate);
```

Comment: So did this work for you? If so, please mark is as the accepted answer. If not, let us know what the problem is so we can try to help. Thanks.